# Is it possible to support both REST & SOAP APIs on a single spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, soap

We have a spring boot application which exposes REST endpoints. There is a requirement to support SOAP endpoints in the same application.

Can someone help out on the below questions as there is very little to no documentation on this part,

1. Can spring boot support both REST & SOAP endpoints, on the same port ?
2. If yes to the above questions, any good documentation or sample project will be really helpful.
3. Is it advisable to have spring boot application configured in this manner ? If no, what are the cons ?

Comment: Sure you can! If you want to use document first style simply create a WSDL and generate the code.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Do you by any chance have some sample spring boot code supporting both REST & SOAP apis ?

Comment: I'll check tomorrow